# How do I plot error bars from a second dataframe of summary stats onto my plotted raw data, ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got my plot how I like it as far as the raw data is concerned. Basically I want something like a bar chart but instead of a filled in bar you can see the raw data points and their confidence intervals. Right now I have all the plotting from my long-format dataframe (`dat`) with raw values. I have summary stats and high and low confidence intervals for each point cloud in a separate dataframe (`sum_stats`)

The original plot call:

```
dat %>% subset(y_var > 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x_var, y = y_var, group = Treatment, col = Treatment, shape = Treatment)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 1.5, dodge.width = 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~comp_group)
```

When I tried adding `geom_error(data = sum_stats, aes(x=x_var, ymin=ci_low, ymax=ci_high)`, I got an error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y_var' not found

When I take the `geom_error()` call back out, the plot comes up no problem.

The image below is 2 of the 4 facets of the plot, but without the confidence intervals over the clouds of data points. How do I get the confidence intervals onto each cloud of points?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot using second data source for error bars fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108269/ggplot-using-second-data-source-for-error-bars-fails)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416267/suddenly-cannot-find-a-factor-after-i-add-a-label-to-my-ggplot/59416651#59416651) for a very similar question...

Answer (score 1):

Without a reproducible example of your data, I can't be sure that my solution is working for your particular dataset. Moreover, I think you made a typo because up to my knowledge, `geom_error` does not exist (`geom_errorbar` yes).

However, if you are looking for plotting the confidence intervals onto each cloud of points you can use `geom_pointrange`. Here an example using the `iris` dataset.

1) Generating the statitical summary from the `iris` dataset

```r
library(dplyr)
iris_stat <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length), SD = sd(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  mutate(Upper = Mean+SD, Lower = Mean-SD)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species     Mean    SD Upper Lower
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa      5.01 0.352  5.36  4.65
2 versicolor  5.94 0.516  6.45  5.42
3 virginica   6.59 0.636  7.22  5.95
```

2) Then, we can plot the cloud of points using `geom_jitter` and the confidence intervals using `geom_pointrange`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_jitter(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, shape = Species),width = 0.2, size = 2)+
  geom_pointrange(data = iris_stat, aes(x = Species, y = Mean, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper))
```

And you get the following plot:
[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

If not, please consider to provide a reproducible example of your data (see: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))